# Get last inserted data of multiple IDs from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `"event_activities"` and it records the activities of all events.

It has a field 'event_id' that is `'id'` in `"events"` table. Now I want to retrieve last inserted row of each event and event should be distinct.

```
event_activities
------------------
id eventid date


events
----------
id name place
```

I have tried using `DISTINCT` but I also need some more fields and I also tried using `group by` but was unsuccessful.

```
select distinct a.id, a.eventid, a.date, b.name from event_activities as a join events as b on a.eventid = b.id;
```

and

```
select a.id, a.eventid, a.date, b.name from event_activities as a join events as b on a.eventid = b.id order by a.eventid;
```

Both queries does not gave me required result.
Can someone bring a query that do my job.

Comment: By "last inserted", do you mean having the latest date value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.eventid, a.date, b.name 
from event_activities as a join events as b on a.eventid = b.id 
where a.date = (select max(date) from event_activities a2 
                where a2.eventid = a.eventid)
order by a.eventid
```